# How to replace an entire sentence with a space in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am new to this platform. Just had a requirement which I have been working over sometime but not able to find it.

If this pattern was to occur in the middle of a line. How to handle it. Suppose the line is like. aaaa ---- bbbb. If i want to erase the ----bbbb part how to do it. But I want to keep the aaaa part as it is in the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using awk:

```
awk '/^--/{$0=" ";}1' file
```

This will repalce the line with a space when it begins with --

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this. Just a question. If this pattern was to occur in the middle of a line. How to handle it. Suppose the line is like. aaaa ---- bbbb. If i want to erase the ----bbbb part how to do it.

Comment: in that case, you use the sed solution just by removing the ^. Its gets a little trickier using awk

Answer (score 4):

You can do it easily with sed:

```
sed -r 's/^--.*//' inputfile > outputfile
```

Or in place:

```
sed -r -i.bak 's/^--.*//' inputfile
```

This will create an inputfile.bak as a backup before modifying the file

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good old `bash` solution:

```
while read -r line; do 
    echo "${line/#--*/}"
done < inputFile > outputFile
```

Comment: +1, though a single `echo "${line/#--*/ }"` would do the trick just as well

Comment: @1_CR Wow, thats creative. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your problem statement what the criteria (limitations) of the solution is.
What you are looking for is something that will support regular expressions. There are a lot of UNIX/Linux tools that can be used to solve this problem.

One simple solution is:

```
# cat file.txt | sed -e "{s/^--.*/ /}"
```

The regular expression "^--.*" will match any line beginning "^" with "--" followed
by any number of characters ".*".  "s" is the sed substitution command.

so "s/^--.*/ /" means, substitute all lines that start with -- and are followed by any
number of characters with a single space.

Comment: Actually the `g` flag would mean that the matching could occur multiple times in the same line. Sed works on all lines by default. And in this case - since the pattern could only match a line once - the global flag is unnecessary

Comment: yes, you are correct. I normally use the sed like syntax in vi which does require g. Thanks for the correction.